# Error 429 Too many requests on stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, rate-limiting, error-message

I'm on a network that apparently makes too many requests to stackoverflow.com (I thought I was the only one)

I get iterations of the following whenever I try to access the domain:

> ```
> Error 429 Too many requests
>
> Too many requests
>
> Guru Mediation:
>
> Details: cache-itm7422-ITM 1470099672 3300317948
>
> Varnish cache server
> ```

Is there anything I can do to regain access? Will I regain access if I just wait?

**Note:** I can get around it if I change networks.

---

**Note:** Long shot maybe, but this might be related to something that happened when I was trying to make screenshots for [this meta.SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329406/how-to-navigate-out-of-draft-view). I was trying to get screenshots for the [Java Arrays topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays) where accessing one of the views froze a tab of my browser.

---

**Note:** The above issue was resolved for me after about one hour.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the site itself. I am getting the same error for stackoverflow.com

Comment: ... or maybe we both just use stackoverflow too much :-)

Comment: Nick Craver tweeted that they're doing some SQL maintenance, so it could be the cause of the problem: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/760235722410459136

Comment: @Quill I (and others) were left in the dark as to him saying he'd post a Stack Status. https://twitter.com/stackstatus I checked that for over an hour and even as I typed this; nothing was posted.